# link to an executable and remove some parameters

Tags: symlink, executable, hard-link

I currently am using Xamarin Studio, which has a bug in this version. It adds 2 parameters to an executable, which causes the output to flood with error messages, slowing down the build time from a minute to at least 10 minutes.

Is there a way I can move the original executable and create a bash script or a link, which removes the 2 offending parameters, and put it in its place?

So Xamarin would run the command as usual, but the 2 offending parameters wouldn't be passed to the original command.

say it's `/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format xml1 --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --auto-activate-custom-fonts --sdk iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk --compilation-directory Main.storyboard`, I'd like to:

1. Move `ibtool` to `ibtool_orig`
2. Put a link or script in place of `ibtool`, which removes the offending parameters and passes it along to `ibtool_orig`
   , giving me the following command:

`/usr/bin/ibtool_orig --errors --output-format xml1 --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --auto-activate-custom-fonts --sdk iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk --compilation-directory Main.storyboard` (notice that `ibtool` is now `ibtool_orig` and `--errors --warnings`is gone)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way is a loop shaped like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for i do # loop over the positional parameters
  case $i in
    --notices|--warnings) ;;
    *) set -- "$@" "$i" # append to the end of the positional parameter
                        # list if neither --notices nor --warnings
  esac
  shift # remove from the head of the positional parameter list
done
exec "${0}_orig" "$@"
```

You can also replace `#! /bin/sh -` with the `ksh`, `zsh`, `yash` or `bash` path and replace `exec` with `exec -a "$0"` so `ibtool_orig` be passed `/path/to/ibtool` as `argv[0]` (which it might use in its error messages or to reexecute itself).

Comment: I though of doing it in such a way, but I wasn't sure whether setting the arguments with `set -- ...` would work properly while you're still iterating through the current list of arguments.

Comment: @wurtel. No the list of arguments to loop on is fixed. It's built upon parsing the for-loop, and the shell doesn't rebuild it at each iteration, that wouldn't make sense. That's different from ksh's `for (( expr1; expr2; expr3 ))` where the `expr2` and `expr3` arithmetic expressions are evaluated at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
new='/usr/bin/ibtool_orig'
for i; do
    if [ "$i" = --errors ] || [ "$i" = --warnings ]; then
        : # skip these
    else
        new="$new $i"
    fi
done
exec $new
```

This assumes that parameters won't have any special shell characters such as quotes, brackets etc.; handling that makes this a lot more complicated and a perl script might then be easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @new = grep(!/^--(errors|warnings)\z/, @ARGV);
exec '/usr/bin/ibtool_orig', @new;
```

Hmm, it's a bit shorter too :)

Comment: I will try this when I get back to work, but in the meantime: I don't understand how this works. You assign `"$new $i"` to a new variable `newargs`, but you don't seem to be using this variable? Could you explain?

Comment: Sorry, I made an error there... the assignment should have been to `new`. I've edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: In this particular case, since none of the arguments contain spaces or wildcard characters, that will work, however in the general case, it's wrong as you're joining the arguments with spaces and then splitting them again (on $IFS), and do globbing on the resulting words.

Comment: That's what I already mentioned, and why I also showed the perl variant. Or are you saying the perl variant suffers from the same problems?

Comment: @wurtel, quotes are not a problem. That's the characters in `$IFS` (taken from the environment in some shells) and the globbing characters (`*`, `[`, `?`).

Comment: You edited the perl example to replace `$` with `\z`; if there is `--errors\n` I would want to replace that as well... so I don't really agree with that edit (and I did mention brackets etc)

Comment: @wurtel, fair enough, that's your answer after all. The OP didn't mention anything about removing a `--errors\n` option though. (that's a mute point here as that's never going to happen but generally using `/^foo$/` to match `foo` literally is wrong as that also matches `foo\n`). Another option would be `grep($_ ne "--notices" && $_ ne "--warnings", @ARGV)` (note that it's --notices the OP wants to remove, not --errors).